# Tree not being traversed in correct order when using chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to perform DFS traversal of a tree structure, stored as the mapping `Root_Node_Value -> Array_of_Children`. When I try to perform the traversal, storing the mapping as a plain object, the tree is traversed as expected.

```js
// Correct DFS 
treeMapping = {'1221':['1223','1224']}

function closeTree(root) {
    const children = treeMapping[root] || [];
    children.forEach(function (child) { closeTree(child) });

    console.log("Closing: "+root);
}
```

The output for the above code, *as expected*, is: `1223, 1224, 1221`

However, when I try to implement the same logic, using `chrome.storage.sync` to retrieve the mapping, the expected order is not followed.

```js
// Incorrect DFS
function closeTree(root) {

  chrome.storage.sync.get(root.toString(), data => {
    const children = data[root] || [];
    children.forEach(function(child) { closeTree(child); });

    console.log("Closing: "+root);
  });
}
```

The code using chrome.storage.sync outputs `1221, 1222, 1226`, even though the tree mapping stored in storage is identical. This is clearly incorrect as the root value, `1221`, should be printed last.

```js
// Retrieved value using chrome.storage.get('1221', ...)
{1221: Array(2)}
    1221: (2) [1222, 1226]
```

**What is the cause for this behavior and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chrome` API is asynchronous. An easy rule of thumb is, if the method accepts a callback per the documentation then it runs asynchronously.

The simplest solution is to *promisify* closeTree and use Promise.all on children:

```
function closeTree(root) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(root.toString(), async data => {
      const children = data[root] || [];
      await Promise.all(children.map(closeTree));
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

P.S. you can optimize considerably by reading all children in one operation:
`chrome.storage.sync.get(children, processAllChildren)`